# Layers disappear when panning in DukeScript Leaflet4j

Tags: javafx, leaflet

I am test driving [Leaflet4j](https://github.com/dukescript/leaflet4j) inside of JavaFX [combo](https://github.com/dukescript/leaflet4j#running-inside-of-javafx-application).

When I run the `l4jfxdemo` project and then drag the map the circle and polygon layers disappear. They do not disappear when zooming. I added a `DragEndListener` to enumerate the layers and they are still there but don't show on the map. When you zoom in or out you can see them appear for a brief moment.

I recompiled `Leaflet4j` with different versions of [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) but it made no difference. I also tried various map options as well as redrawing of the layers after panning but still no joy.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

After the map dragging ends (when DragEndListener is triggered), try explicitly redrawing the layers. Sometimes, dragging the map might trigger a rendering issue that can be resolved by forcing a redraw.